# Using web services in dialog click button but getting error

Tags: android, web-services

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int p,long arg3) {

    showPopUp(users[p],ids[p]);
}
});

public void showPopUp(String username,final String toid){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Challenge");
    builder.setMessage("Do You Want to Challenge "+username+"..??");
    builder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String npath = cpath+toid;
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(npath);
            Log.d("Challenge path" ,npath+"");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
                Log.d("execution result " ,response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"");
                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
                {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(data);
                    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
                    jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(0);
                    String error = jobj.getString("errormsg");
                    Log.d("challenge response", data);
                    if(error.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Challenge Has Started. Play Your Turn", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DicesTwoColumn.class);
                        intent.putExtra("fromid", LoginScreen.uid);
                        intent.putExtra("toid", toid);
                        String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_localgame (from_id,to_id,status) VALUES ('"+LoginScreen.uid+"','"+toid+"','active')";
                        db.execSQL(sql);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You already sent a challenge to this user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("No", null);
    builder.show();
}
```

**this is the logcat results**

```
05-06 10:39:57.622: D/Challenge path(875): http://www.base29.com/base3/Yatzy/challengeuser.php?fromid=7&toid=1
05-06 10:39:57.671: D/AndroidRuntime(875): Shutting down VM
05-06 10:39:57.671: W/dalvikvm(875): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.isStale(SocketInputBuffer.java:109)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.isStale(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:205)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.isStale(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:185)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:336)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.base29.flipit.GamePlayersList$2.onClick(GamePlayersList.java:86)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-06 10:39:57.802: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**It not goes into the try{ } body . On logcat it show `Log.d("Challenge path" ,npath+"");` but getting force close error. Works on gingerbread emulator but now works on ice-cream-sandwitch**

Comment: plz also add logcat results with question if you are getting runtime error and if you are getting compile time error then point out in which line currently you are getting error

Comment: ok i add the logcat text. please check now whats wrong with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not perform a networking operation on its main thread. For this reason you must use handler or asynctask.